# Using !! in JS expressions

Tags: javascript

```
const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser;
```

The author advice to use !!authUser instead of authUser.
Is there any difference between authUser and !!authUser?

Comment: !! will make your function return a boolean (true or false) instead of anything that authUser might be.

Comment: The `authCondition` function can be replaced by the built-in `Boolean`.